# How to make item visible only if statement boolean in android

Tags: java, android, if-statement, boolean

I have static constant top navigation menu with the following item

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_camera"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_gallery"
    android:enabled="true"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

and I have two class MainActivity and SecondActivity

I wanna make both item appear only if condition met

Exemple : If user clicked on second Activity display both item.

MainActivity

```
//action bar menu
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     //inflate menu
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.top_navigation_menu, menu);
     return true;
 }
 //handle actionbar item clicks
 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     int id = item.getItemId();
     if (id == R.id.action_camera){
         //OpenCamera
     }
     if (id == R.id.action_gallery){
         //OpenGallery
     }
     return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do as follows:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     //inflate menu
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.top_navigation_menu, menu);

    MenuItem action_camera_menu_item = menu.findItem(R.id.action_camera);
    MenuItem action_gallery = menu.findItem(R.id.action_gallery);

    action_camera_menu_item.setVisible(conditionOK);
    action_gallery.setVisible(conditionOK);

    return true;
 }
```

Comment: How do I replace conditionOk into secondActivity class onclick button

Comment: You could add the conditionOk as an attribute of your Application class, or pass its value as a parcelable to your SecondActivity's onCreate()

Comment: Please just use action_camera_menu_item.setVisible(conditionOK); instead of "if" construct. Upvoted.

Comment: Note: `invalidateOptionsMenu()` needs to be called if the condition updates at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your "condition" is available while onCreateOptionsMenu being called, you can get your menu item by ID like this menu.findItem(...) and then do `setVisible(boolean visible)` for it.