# How to enable xml Button in a Activity class?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

I have this item in my top_navigation_menu layout I would like to enable it in my **OnCreate** method programmatically:

```
    <item
    android:id="@+id/action_button"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:visible="false"
    android:clickable = "false" />
```

Exemple : When User Open New Activity Enable this Item.

Edit : this is a follow up from my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58917633/how-to-make-item-visible-only-if-statement-boolean-in-android) so I'm trying another approach.

Edit : after some research I found

```
   Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_button);
    btn.setEnabled(true);
    btn.setClickable(true);
```

Not sure which one I should use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused about what you want to achieve.
Visible, clickable and enable are same components attr state with different output

> 1. `visible` is your button visibility if you set it value to `false` it gonna be gone and clear the `Rect` from the screen also
> 2. `enable` it's mean prevents the user from tapping the `Button`. The appearance of enabled and non-enabled `Button` may differ, if the
>      `drawables` referenced
> 3. `clickable` it's mean how your `Button` reacts to click events. false mean disable the click events

What can I see is you tried to put them all, which is bad for me. One state is enough depending on what you trying to achieve for. This is examples and my suggestions :

1. Enable State, XML :

   ```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/action_button"
       android:enabled="false"/>
   ```
2. Visibility State, XML :

   ```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/action_button"
       android:visible="false"/>
   ```
3. Clickable State, XML :

   ```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/action_button"
       android:clickable="false"/>
   ```

And then from your `OnCreate` you can change change their state as follow

```
Button myButton = findViewById(R.id.action_button);
//for visibility state
myButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
//for enable state
myButton.setEnable(true);
//for clickable state
myButton.setClickable(true);
```

Comment: Thanks one last question is using <Item> apply the same way as the button in my activity ??

Comment: no it isn't, you should change those <Item></Item> with <Button></Button>

Answer (score 0):

in your xml instead of "item" use "Button"

in onCreate():

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_button);
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
button.setEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks but what's the difference between setClickable setEnabled

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615823/setenabled-vs-setclickable-what-is-the-difference